# Haar functions are basis in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Define the Haar functions as $e_0^0=1$ and for $n\ge 1$, $k=1,\ldots,2^n$ 
$$
e_n^k(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & \mbox{if $x \in \big(\frac{K-1}{2^n},\frac{K}{2^n}\big)$};\\
        -2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & \mbox{if $x \in \big(\frac{K}{2^n},\frac{K+1}{2^n}\big)$};\\
0 &\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
$$
As part of showing that this is an orthonormal basis in $L^2[0,1]$, I need to show first that if $\langle f,e^k\rangle=0$ for each $k$ and $n$ then $\langle f,\chi_{[0,x]}\rangle = 0$ for every dyadic $x$. This would mean $f=0$.

I was looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326317/281040) answer but I do not understand the construction he uses. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use $f_n^j := \frac1{2^{\frac{n-1}2}} e_n^j$ since they have the same linear span, denote it by $S$.

We shall prove by induction on $n$ that $$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right)} \in S, \quad \text{ for all } n \ge 0, 1 \le k \le 2^n.$$

Indeed, if $n=1$ then
$$\chi_{(0,1)} \stackrel{\text{a.e.}}{=} e_0^0$$
so $\chi_{(0,1)} \in S$.

Assume that for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we have
$$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right)} \in S, \quad \text{ for all } 1 \le k \le 2^n.$$

Pick an *odd* number $1 \le k \le 2^{n+1}-1$, or in other words $k=2r+1$ with $1 \le r \le 2^n-1$. We have
$$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}\right)} - \chi_{\left(\frac{k}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)} = f_{n+1}^k\in S,$$
$$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}\right)} + \chi_{\left(\frac{k}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)} \stackrel{\text{a.e.}}{=} \chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)} = \chi_{\left(\frac{r}{2^n},\frac{r+1}{2^n}\right)} \in S$$
using the assumption. By taking $\frac12$ of the sum and difference, we get
$$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}\right)},\chi_{\left(\frac{k}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)} \in S$$
which covers all of them so
$$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}\right)} \in S, \quad \text{ for all } 1 \le k \le 2^{n+1}$$
finishes the induction.

Now for any dyadic interval we have
$$\chi_{\left(0,\frac{k}{2^n}\right)} = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \chi_{\left(\frac{j-1}{2^n},\frac{j}{2^n}\right)} \in S$$
which proves your claim.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on $h_m$? I can't see how the 1, -1 stuff follows.

Comment: @blancmange Indeed, it's wrong and at the moment I don't see how to fix it. I'll think about it.

Comment: I think it's easy to show inductively that we can generate $\chi_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right]}$ using Haar functions. Then we only need to add those pieces together.

Comment: @blancmange Well, if $f^j_n := \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n-1}2}} e^j_n$ then $$\chi_{\left(\frac{k-1}{2^n}, \frac{k}{2^n}\right)} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{j-1} f_{n+j}^{\frac{2^jk-1}{2^{n+1}}}$$
in the sense of pointwise almost everywhere convergence, but *not* in $L^2$. Any other ideas?

Comment: @blancmange You were right, induction was the way to go.

Comment: Actually I find it not so obvious the step after showing $\chi_{\left(0,\frac{k}{2^n}\right)}$. We need to approximate for each real intervals $(0,a)$ and apply measure theory arguments.

Comment: @blancmange Of course, we are far from over but this is what the OP wanted to prove, the rest seems clear to them. Anyway, there exists a sequence of dyadic fractions $(x_n)_n$ such that $x_n \to a$ and then it follows that $\chi_{(0,x_n)}\to \chi_{(0,a)}$ in $L^2$ so  $\chi_{(0,a)} \in \overline{S}$. Now we get $$\int_{0}^a f = 0$$
for all $a=0$. This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/274702/144766) implies that $f=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For some $n$ let $g \in L^2[0,1]$ be constant on each interval $[(k-1)/2^n,k/2^n)$ then $g = C +\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} b_k e_n^k$ where $b_k = 2^{-(n-1)/2} \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} g(m/2^n)$ and $C= \int_0^1 g(x)dx$

The Haar orthonormal basis is obtained by using this iteratively to show the $e_n^{2k}$ can be discarded